# (Python) pandas.DataFrame doesn't update value each for-loop cycle, why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas DataFrame and was curious why my basic thinking of adding new values to a new line doesn't work here.

I also tried using different ways with .loc[], .append(), but obciously used them in an incorrect way (still plenty to learn).

Instructions
Add a column to data named length, defined as the length of each word.
Add another column named frequency, which is defined as follows for each word in data:

- If count > 10, frequency is "frequent".
- If 1 < count <= 10, frequency
  is "infrequent".
- If count == 1, frequency is "unique".

  My if sentenses record for all DataFrame only by last value of dictionary like object (Counter from pandas/numpy?). Word and count values are all returned within for cycle, so I don't understand why DataFrame cannot append values each cycle

  ```
  data['length'] = ''
  data['frequency'] = ''

  for word, count in counted_text.items():
      if count > 10:
          data.length = len(word)
          data.frequency = 'frequent'
      if 1 < count <=10:
          data.length = len(word)
          data.frequency = 'infrequent'
      if count == 1:
          data.length = len(word)
          data.frequency = 'unique'
  print(word, len(word), '\n')

  """
  This is working code that I googled
  -----------------------------------
  data = pd.DataFrame({
      "word": list(counted_text.keys()),
      "count": list(counted_text.values())
  })

  data["length"] = data["word"].apply(len)

  data.loc[data["count"] > 10,  "frequency"] = "frequent"
  data.loc[data["count"] <= 10, "frequency"] = "infrequent"
  data.loc[data["count"] == 1,  "frequency"] = "unique"

  """

  print(data.head(), '\n')
  print(data.tail())
  ```

**Output:**

```
finis 5 

       word  count  length frequency
1       the    935       5    unique
2  tragedie      3       5    unique
3        of    576       5    unique
4    hamlet     97       5    unique
5            45513       5    unique 

              word count  length frequency
5109  shooteexeunt     1       5    unique
5110      marching     1       5    unique
5111         peale     1       5    unique
5112           ord     1       5    unique
5113         finis     1       5    unique
```

Comment: The working code that you Googled is the right way to update rows in pandas based on specific conditions. You should never attempt to update rows in a data-frame by using loops. If you scrutinize the loop you've written when you say `data.length = len(word)`, what row_number are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only `word` and `count` in the `data` dataframe and that `count` will not have a value of `0`, you could try the following -

```
import numpy as np
data['length'] = data['word'].str.len()
data['frequency'] = np.where(data['count'] > 10, 'frequent',\
                             np.where((data['count'] > 1) & (data['count'] <= 10),\
                             'infrequent', 'unique'))
```

Comment: Works. But I was looking also for an aswer why // if count > 10: 
        data.length = len(word) ///  took last value of for-loop?

Comment: I think in each iteration of the `for-loop`, you are re-assigning the value to `data.length` and `data.frequency`. So, the last value obtained at the end of the `for-loop` is being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

After @Sajan gave a valid code, I came to a conclusion, that DataFrame doesn't need for-loop at all.